Angular-calendar: during navigation week view is rendered next to previous week view
I am using the angular-calendar component in an Ionic Angular project and have problems implementing a calendar in week view. When navigating the calendar (forward or backward), the week view gets duplicated and appears in the same view. The picture below shows what I mean.
I am looking for the cause of this.

My main.ts:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { browserLocalPersistence, indexedDBLocalPersistence, provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { IonicModule, isPlatform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideHttpClient, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideRouter, withPreloading, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { routes } from './app/app-routing.module';
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFi from '@angular/common/locales/fi';

import { firebaseConfig } from './config/app.config';

enableProdMode();

registerLocaleData(localeFi);

export function translationLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideFirebaseApp( () => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (isPlatform('android')) {
        auth.setPersistence(indexedDBLocalPersistence);
      } else {
        auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)),
    importProvidersFrom(
      IonicModule.forRoot(),
      IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
      ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
        enabled: !isPlatform('android'),
        registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
      }),
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (translationLoader),
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      }),
      CalendarModule.forRoot({
        provide: DateAdapter,
        useFactory: adapterFactory
      })
    )
  ]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

The calendar in the HTML template:
<mwl-calendar-week-view
  [locale]="locale"
  [refresh]="refresh"
  [viewDate]="calendarView.date"
  [dayStartHour]="calendarConfig.dayStartHour"
  [dayEndHour]="calendarConfig.dayEndHour"
  [weekStartsOn]="1"
  [hourDuration]="60"
  [hourSegments]="calendarConfig.hourSegments"
  [excludeDays]="calendarConfig.excludeDays"
  [events]="events"
  (eventClicked)="handleEvent($event)"
  (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
>
</mwl-calendar-week-view>

The events in the image are populated correctly and show up as expected. My instinct tells me something is wrong with the imports, but whatever I tried fails to give the desired result.
Any ideas?
